# JSON Schema enum with maximum and minimum

Tags: json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I have a JSON object like this.

```json
{
  "test": bla bla bla
}
```

This `test` can be a number between 0 and 120 or an empty string. I want to validate this JSON object using a JSON schema like this.

```json
{
  "type": ["number", "string"],
  "enum": [""],
  "minimum": 0,
  "maximum": 120
}
```

Valid

```json
{"test": ""}
{"test": 0}
{"test": 120}
{"test": 3}
```

Invalid

```json
{"test": "dfd"}
{"test": -1}
{"test": 675}
```

What is the correct JSON schema for this? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this schema

```json
{
  "anyOf":[
    {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [""]
    },
    {
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": 0,
        "maximum": 120
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this will be helpful